# Copy line in multiple positions in vim

Tags: vim, copy-paste

I'd like to copy current line in vim editor to some different places. Is there a way to do it with one command?

The following is impossible command illustrating what I mean.

```
:t 25, 28, 54
```

Of course I can do it with

```
:t 25
:t 29
:t 56
```

However I'd prefer make it with the only command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it using pipe to concatenate commands:

```
:t 25 | t 28 | t 54
```

Comment: after you `:t 25` the original 28 -> 29, so your command won't give correct output.

Comment: Then start with the highest number.

Answer (score 1):

For something like that, you need a custom command, e.g. this:

```
:command! -nargs=+ T for lnum in reverse([<f-args>]) | exe 'copy' lnum | endfor
```

Invoke it via `:T 25 28 54`.

By processing the arguments from last to first, this avoids adapting the line numbers for the added lines.

Comment: May want to sort the line number in case they are not already in ascending order

Comment: @PeterRincker: Yes, but numerical sorting requires a custom comparator, and that would complicate the answer too much. But for a plugin, definitely!